# C# put pc to sleep or hibernate

Tags: c#, hibernate, sleep

I want to put my system to either sleep or hibernate, two different options.

How would I do this with API's, I don't really want to use Process, and that doesn't allow me to choose what method I want for this action.

Comment: You can find all the information you need in this [link](http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial177_Lock-Stand-By-Hibernate-and-Log-Off.html) for locking the PC, stand by mode, hibernating and logging off.

Comment: Thanks, I needed the lock PC code as well.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

```
// Hibernate
Application.SetSuspendState(PowerState.Hibernate, true, true);
// Standby
Application.SetSuspendState(PowerState.Suspend, true, true);
```

Or, if you like system calls:

```
[DllImport("Powrprof.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling=true)]
public static extern bool SetSuspendState(bool hiberate, bool forceCritical, bool disableWakeEvent);

// Hibernate
SetSuspendState(true, true, true);
// Standby
SetSuspendState(false, true, true);
```

Comment: So how to do this in windows 8?

Comment: @fre0n It is not firing the event PowerModeChanged when the system got invoked.

Comment: In case anyone is searching for this and is not using WinForms, 'Application' is in the System.Windows.Forms namespace. Just need to import the reference and all works sweetly (on Win7, at least).

Comment: @fre0n You are missing a comma at "PowerState.Suspend".

Comment: @HockeyJ I think using the P/Invoke / DLL is probably better than importing the whole WinForms namespace; if you need to use this in a WPF solution.

Comment: For those that are not sure what to import: using System.Windows.Forms;

Comment: Danny is accurate. If you only need the call, importing the entire namespace isn't needed. Copy the DLLImport and make the call as shown.  All the Forms library does is wrap that or a similar call. 

Just verified the DLLImport worked for .net core.  Thank you for the elegant solution.

Comment: For the standby case wouldn't you want disableWakeEvent set to false so any keyboard or mouse click event wakes the system back up, e.g. SetSuspendState(false, true, false); ?