# Suspending a PC

Tags: c#, uwp, suspend

I'm fairly new to C#, I am trying to write my own UWP app to suspend the PC after a user entered interval.

I have managed to get my timer working but I am struggling to understand how to call the method to suspend the computer. I tried using the code suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2080083/2505109)

```
Application.SetSuspendState(PowerState.Suspend, true, true);
```

But I get the following error when I try to build the project:

> `CS0117    'Application' does not contain a definition for 'SetSuspendState'   SystemTimer C:\Users\xxxxx\Source\Workspaces\Workspace\SystemTimer\SystemTimer\MainPage.xaml.cs 52`

I found an MSDN entry on [`PowerState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.powerstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which suggest I use the `System.Windows.Form` library. I tried adding it to the namespaces but get an error saying that `Form` is not an available namespace in `System.Windows`.

I feel I am probably missing something fundamental but I am not entirely sure what it is.

Comment: What version of the .NET framework are you targeting?

Comment: Look at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.setsuspendstate(v=vs.110).aspx) and it will tell you which assembly you need to reference and which namespace you'll find the classes you need. In this case you need a reference to `System.Windows.Forms.dll` and you'll need the namespace (add with a `using` statement) `System.Windows.Forms`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# put pc to sleep or hibernate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079813/c-sharp-put-pc-to-sleep-or-hibernate)

Comment: @ChrisF I guess 4.5 or 4.6, this is just a learning exercise that won't go beyond my own PC

Comment: @series0ne The OP has linked that question in the question saying it didn't work so I doubt it is a dupe

Comment: @TheLethalCoder I didn't read fully before flagging as duplicate :-|

Comment: Have a look over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31647827/handling-suspend-resume-and-activation-in-windows-10-uwp Though I don't know enough about the subject to know if it'll help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I feel I am probably missing something fundamental but I am not entirely what it is.

The world of (UWP) apps is a different world. An app is not supposed to interfere (i.e. to mess around) with its underlying system. You basically run in a sandboxed environment and you only get what is provided by the API. Shutting down or suspending the system is not part of this API.

What options do you have? You probably are better off if you create a desktop app. Then you will be able to use all the available desktop APIs including `System.Windows.Form`.

Comment: I think this is probably the best option for me while I am trying to get familiar with the environment. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried implementing this using Interop Services?

```
[DllImport("Powrprof.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling=true)]
public static extern bool SetSuspendState(bool hiberate, bool forceCritical, bool disableWakeEvent);

// Hibernate
SetSuspendState(true, true, true);
// Standby
SetSuspendState(false, true, true);
```

Comment: This won't work as you can't call pinvoke arbitrary Win32 functions. Only a limited set is available, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br205757.aspx. Why is that so? Would you use `DllImport` your app no longer will be "universal" but strongly tied to a particular platform.